# Access, combobox with multiple selections: how to see if an certain item is included?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

In my Access form I have a ComboBox that allows multiple selection. I would like to see if a certain item is selected. How to do?

It would be great if exists something like:

```
if Me.<ComboBox name>.Options.<Item_5>.Selected = True Then
   msgbox "it is included"
End If
```

Comment: Do you mean a list box? Combo boxes don't have multiple selections.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth well, actually it is a `ComboBox` whose `Control Source` is a  table's field that has been set with a lookup: `Row Source` is a list and `Allow Multiple Values` is `Yes`. I know that this is a blasphemous way to use Access, but this is the best way form my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the Control Source of the ComboBox points to a field which may contain multiple values, the Value property of the ComboBox returns an array.

Therefore, the task is reduced to testing whether the array contains the item in question, which may be achieved using the following (amongst other ways):

```
InStr(1, Join(<ComboBoxName>.Value, ","), <Item_5>) > 0
```

**EDIT:** Following Erik's comment, the below may be a more appropriate way to test for the presence of the item:

```
Dim itm As Variant
Dim rtn As Boolean
For Each itm In <ComboBoxName>.Value
    If itm = <Item_5> Then
        rtn = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next itm
If rtn Then MsgBox "Item is included"
```

Comment: Using `Join` and `InStr` to test if an item is present in an array is a bad practice. You should iterate through the array. Consider the array (apple, pineapple). Pineapple is selected, apple isn't, and you want to test if apple is selected. Your code will say it's selected, even though it isn't. Furthermore, if you want to test if a substring is present in a string, `LIKE` is the preferred way to do that.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Good point - I suppose one could surround the test item with the chosen delimiter to mitigate against this, but that would still fail for arrays which contain items already surrounded by the chosen delimiter.